# jQuery button ui-btn-right wrong position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, button

I have 2 buttons, which I would like to display in left and right end (both at bottom) of the screen.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
<fieldset>
    <button  id = "back" class="ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline" data-position="fixed" onClick="getPrevious()">Previous</button >
    <button id = "next" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline" data-position="fixed" onClick="getNext()">Next</button>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried adding `ui-btn-right`..

```
<button id = "next" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline" data-position="fixed" onClick="getNext()">Next</button>
```

But, it displayed as . You can see the positioning is not in-line.

[image]

Am I missing something here. Also, I am trying to position these button at bottom of the mobile screen, above the footer. Trying to find the work around for it too.

I tried adding the below styling:

```
style="bottom: 50px ; position: fixed"
```

but the buttons overlapped

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align: middle;` ?

Comment: @guest271314 [Added this](http://jsfiddle.net/nbfgcv51/).. but unfortunately, it displays wrongly..

Comment: @gabe I tried, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ui-btn-left` class to your "Previous" button to remove the margin applied on it by `ui-btn` class

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ui-btn-left` , `ui-btn-icon-left` class to "Previous" button

```
  <div data-role="page">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <fieldset>
                <button id="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inline" data-position="fixed">Previous</button>
                <button id="next" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline" data-position="fixed">Next</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nbfgcv51/1/